# Return inside loop for C++ breaks loop?

Tags: c++

I am reversing a doubly linked list. My function for the same is :

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
    // Complete this function
    // Do not write the main method. 
    Node* temp = new Node();
    if ( head == NULL) { return head; }
    while ( head != NULL) {
        temp = head->next;
        head->next = head->prev;
        head->prev = temp;
        if (temp == NULL ) { break; }
        head = temp;
    }
    return head;
}
```

This works correctly.
Instead of using the break command, if I do  'return head' than the function exits the while loop and has a compile error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
    // Complete this function
    // Do not write the main method. 
    Node* temp = new Node();
    if ( head == NULL) { return head; }
    while ( head != NULL) {
        temp = head->next;
        head->next = head->prev;
        head->prev = temp;
        if (temp == NULL ) { return head; }
        head = temp;
    }
 }
```

What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: Can you post the compiler error message?

Comment: I think this is because all code paths must return a Node*. It may never happen in runtime, but there's still a path after your while loop.

Comment: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]

Comment: `Node* temp = new Node();` you're leaking memory. you probably wanted to start with `Node* temp = head`, then all your problems are going away automatically - try it out.

Comment: @ShubhamLalwani you should include the error message in your _question_, not in a comment. (Edit the question!).

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the compiler doesn't know that `temp` will always end up being `NULL` at some point, it only knows the loop can end, and the function will have no return statement.

As **CompuChip** pointed out, you may add the following line at the end, to appease the compiler:

```
throw std::runtime_error("Control should never reach this point");
```

Or you may simply return `NULL` at the end.

Comment: And a possible fix: add `throw std::runtime_error("Control should never reach this point");` right before the closing bracket.

Comment: @CompuChip, I like that, but it won't work for the misguided souls that turn off exception support (it's a real thing, which I disagree with, but I digress).

Comment: true, but I don't expect that from someone who uses `-Werror` :)

Answer (score 1):

What you know, but the compiler doesn't, is that the condition `temp == NULL` will be true before `head != NULL` becomes false. It assumes that the `while` loop may end naturally (with `head == NULL`) and therefore a return statement is missing.

Changing the `while` loop condition to `1` (true) will probably resolve the warning. (It is a *warning* after all, not really an error; it becomes an error because you've asked it to using `-Werror`).

Better still would be to avoid changing altering control flow as much as you do (avoid `break` where possible). This makes the code easier to understand for other humans and for the compiler:

```
Node* Reverse(Node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL) { return head; }
    Node* temp = head->next;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        head->next = head->prev;
        head->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
        temp = head->next;
    }
    return head;
 }
```

Comment: It is a hard error with the proper compilation flags (and a good thing it is, too). It best to leave it at a error level.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't consider it a good thing when a false-positive warning becomes an error.

Comment: It's an error indicative of a bad coding practice. I had the misfortune of fixing mysterious bugs that such code can cause when a change is introduced.

Comment: @StoryTeller If the compiler is reasonably good at eliminating false positives (which modern compilers arguably are) then we might be inclined to treat the warnings they do produce as errors, as you suggest. Sometimes this is reasonable. Other times code is most naturally expressed in ways that the compiler will generate a false-positive warning for, though. I don't believe it's a universal truth that "it's an error indicative of a bad coding practice".